# React Native Google Maps with Autocomplete get the location

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm implementing the same exact code of React Native Google Maps with Autocomplete, from this link: https://medium.com/@Mdmoin07/react-native-google-maps-with-autocomplete-45a5617be2f5

I'm trying to get the location searched from the class MapContainer but i can t figure it out.

```
class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
        region: {}
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getInitialState();
    }

    getInitialState() {
        getLocation().then(
            (data) => {
                this.setState({
                    region: {
                        latitude: data.latitude,
                        longitude: data.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.003
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }

    getCoordsFromName(loc) {
        this.setState({
            region: {
                latitude: loc.lat,
                longitude: loc.lng,
                latitudeDelta: 0.003,
                longitudeDelta: 0.003
            }
        });
    }

    onMapRegionChange(region) {
        this.setState({ region });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.region,"fgg")
       // console.log(data.description); what should i write to show data?
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <MapInput notifyChange={(loc) => this.getCoordsFromName(loc)}
                    />
                </View>

                {
                    this.state.region['latitude'] ?
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <MyMapView
                                region={this.state.region}
                                onRegionChange={(reg) => this.onMapRegionChange(reg)} />
                        </View> : null}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default MapContainer;
```

as you see i can get the lat lng from the region(console.log(this.state.region,"fgg")) but how can i get the location like the name of the city for example.
i hope i made it clear enough, i'll appreciate you helping.thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay. I faced the similar issue and in my case, it was the incorrect configuration on Google developer console.

To get names and addresses, I needed to enable `Places Api` on my project on `Google developer console` and the code started working.

Comment: thx for your reply,but how can i consol log the location choosen? not the lat lng, but the actual name of the city

Comment: You cannot get it directly from Maps, you need to use another package for it.
React Native GeoCoding (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoding) is a great example of it. So you need to get the lat long from Map, and use them to call the geocoder to get the address, city name etc.